# Dynamic Form-Validation

Tags: asp.net, validation, parsley.js

Is there any possibility that

1. Parsley tags are generated in an external file
2. This external file is then linked with the page to apply validation
   just like CSS and JS are linked

I like attribute based validation but we are introducing dynamic validation i.e. instead of hard coding parsely attributes, validation rules will be in a config file through which parsely attributes will be generated and applied on a page.

I will definitely welcome any other idea (other than parsley) to achieve dynamic form-validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "dynamic validation", since you will always have to know which attributes to add for each field.

However, it is possible to use Parsley (or any other validation plugin based on attributes, for that matter) as long as you add those attributes before applying parsley() to the form.

Take this example ([jsfiddle available](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/5qesL8yz/)):

```
<form id="myForm" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="requiredField" name="username" />
    <input type="text" id="minLength" name="otherfield" />

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // this can be in another JS file. You must guarantee that this code
        // is executed before .parsley();
        $("#requiredField").attr('data-parsley-required', true);
        $("#minLength").attr('data-parsley-minlength', '6');

        $('#myForm').parsley();
    });
</script>
```

The attributes are added via jQuery, which can be in another JS file. You have to make sure that the attributes are correctly setted before calling `$("#myForm").parsley()`.

Like I stated earlier, this is possible in every jQuery vaildation plugin as long as they use attributes. This means that this method can also be applied in this [jQuery Validation Engine from posabsolute](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine).

Comment: Thanks. But, this (DOM manipulation) will be executed every time the page is refreshed, right? If yes then don't you think it will be slower than a linked JS file having `onblur` event to check if a field is required?

Comment: You're correct, it will be executed every time the user refreshes the page. I don't think setting the attributes via JS will be slower (unless you have a few dozen fields). I guess the main question is: _do you want to create your own validation system?_ I think Parsley can help with the messages (and localization) and custom validators, but this really depends on the needs of your project.